# В чем разница в Css селекторах между ^= и |=?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Например между:
`a[href^='http']` или `a[href|='http']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|=`  требует совпадения первого *слова* значения аттрибута (разделителем слов считается `-`)
 `^=` - просто совпадения начала значения аттрибута:

```css
[class^="top"] {
    background: green;
}

[class|="top"] {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="toptoptop">попадает только под первый селектор</span>
<span class="top-something">попадает под оба, применяется второй</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

`a[href^='http']` - href ссылки начинается с http

`a[href|='http']` - href ссылки начинается с http после которого идёт дефис ИЛИ равен http

Источник: [https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors#селекторы-атрибутов](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors#%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Не совсем, второй случай трактуется иначе

Стиль применяется к элементам, у которых атрибут начинается с указанного значения или с фрагмента значения, после которого идёт дефис. В вашем примере тоже указан дефис, надо было упомянуть про него

http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/selektory-atributov

Comment: Спасибо, обновил ответ